# How do I clear the build cache that is causing gcc 4.9.3 to be used instead of 4.9.4?

Tags: ruby, gcc, bundler

Has anyone see this before?

```
Installing json 1.8.6 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/davidvezzani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170317-7715-43clev.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make  clean

make
compiling generator.c
make: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9.3/bin/gcc-4.9: No such file or directory
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/davidvezzani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/json-1.8.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/davidvezzani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/1.9.1/json-1.8.6/gem_make.out
```

From terminal

```
➜  ~ brew doctor
Your system is ready to brew.

➜  ~ ls /usr/local/Cellar|grep gcc
gcc@4.9

gcc --version
gcc (Homebrew GCC 4.9.4) 4.9.4
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

It appears that my gcc is 4.9.4 and somewhere 4.9.3 is cached.  I'm not sure how/where to clean that out.  How can I best resolve this?

Comment: What gcc files do you have in /usr/local/bin and where do they point? `ls -ld /usr/local/bin/gcc*`.

Comment: Thanks, Casper; https://gist.github.com/dcvezzani/96a09b0cbce2d527e579ddd837d51e81

Comment: I found references to the wrong path in the Makefile cached with the gems under `.rvm`.  I tried to same myself some time on my pristine mac by copying over the `.rvm` directory from my previous host.  I need to find out how to rebuild the gems, first cleaning out and regenerating the Makefiles in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help on linux.

ccache -C